# Extract text values from a dataframe (like operators) - Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

| Column |
| --- |
| Cannot change name of 1173wow17485 of client account . Rerun 1173wow17485 for 06-22-2022 date. |
| Cannot change name of 671wow3614 of client account . Rerun 671wow3614 for 06-28-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 942wow405 of client account . Rerun 942wow40563 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 94wow4064 of client account . Rerun 942wow40564 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 9412wow40565 of client account . Rerun 942wow40565 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 942wow40566 of client account . Rerun 942wow40566 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 942wow4567 of client account . Rerun 942wow40567 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 9422wow40569 of client account . Rerun 942wow40569 for 06-11-2021 date. |
| Cannot change name of 92wow40571 of client account . Rerun 942wow40571 for 06-11-2021 date. |

I would like to extract all the accounts that contain 'wow' in between and the date specified in each row to have something like this:

| Column | Account | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cannot change name of 1173wow17485 of client account . Rerun 1173wow17485 for 06-22-2022 date. | 1173wow17485 | 06-22-2022 |
| Cannot change name of 671wow3614 of client account . Rerun 671wow3614 for 06-28-2021 date. | 671wow3614 | 06-28-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow405 of client account . Rerun 942wow40563 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow405 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 94wow4064 of client account . Rerun 942wow40564 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow40564 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 9412wow40565 of client account . Rerun 942wow40565 for 06-11-2021 date. | 9412wow40565 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow40566 of client account . Rerun 942wow40566 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow40566 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow4567 of client account . Rerun 942wow40567 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow4567 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 9422wow40569 of client account . Rerun 942wow40569 for 06-11-2021 date. | 9422wow40569 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 92wow40571 of client account . Rerun 942wow40571 for 06-11-2021 date. | 92wow40571 | 06-11-2021 |

I've tried several ways but looks like I cannot find a way of extracting the LIKE "wow" part.

Comment: You need either a regex or get creative with the `in` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df[["Acount", "Date"]] = df["Column"].str.extract(
    r"\b(\d+wow\d+)\b.*?(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})"
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

| Column | Acount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cannot change name of 1173wow17485 of client account . Rerun 1173wow17485 for 06-22-2022 date. | 1173wow17485 | 06-22-2022 |
| Cannot change name of 671wow3614 of client account . Rerun 671wow3614 for 06-28-2021 date. | 671wow3614 | 06-28-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow405 of client account . Rerun 942wow40563 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow405 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 94wow4064 of client account . Rerun 942wow40564 for 06-11-2021 date. | 94wow4064 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 9412wow40565 of client account . Rerun 942wow40565 for 06-11-2021 date. | 9412wow40565 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow40566 of client account . Rerun 942wow40566 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow40566 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 942wow4567 of client account . Rerun 942wow40567 for 06-11-2021 date. | 942wow4567 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 9422wow40569 of client account . Rerun 942wow40569 for 06-11-2021 date. | 9422wow40569 | 06-11-2021 |
| Cannot change name of 92wow40571 of client account . Rerun 942wow40571 for 06-11-2021 date. | 92wow40571 | 06-11-2021 |